Microsoft Power Automate Forward Slash error in JSON text String
Having a bit of a problem with handling the naming of specific fields that grab data from SmartSheet and then pass this data to an excel file, just with 3 columns due to power automate not liking the forward slash smart characters.
if(contains(items('Apply_to_each'),'Tier 2/3 Fire Threat Area'),items('Apply_to_each')?['Tier 2/3 Fire Threat Area'],'')

Get the following error:

Flow save failed with code 'WorkflowOperationParametersExtraParameter' and message 'The API operation does not contain a definition for parameter 'item/Tier 2.3 Fire Threat Area'.'.

Been looking up several methods to solve this but since I need the name to match from smartsheet to the excel file it's difficult to change the name itself. Anyone have any idea if there is a way to force power automate to accept the forward slash? Or am I going to have to change the special character after parsing the JSON?
Already tried:
if(contains(items('Apply_to_each'),'Tier 2//3 Fire Threat Area'),items('Apply_to_each')?['Tier 2//3 Fire Threat Area'],'')

if(contains(items('Apply_to_each'),'Tier 2"//"3 Fire Threat Area'),items('Apply_to_each')?['Tier 2"//"3 Fire Threat Area'],'')

Have not tried changing the special character, as this would force me to also change the characters in the excel sheet as well, thought it may be easier to just find a way to get Power Automate to accept the character instead of making a bunch of changes.

what happens if you put the string in double quotes like "Tier 2//3 Fire Threat Area"

Tested it but with no luck. Still throwing the same error at me. May have to throw in the towel and just replace the character.
